# Eclipse - make overriden methods and class final by default

Tags: java, eclipse, final

When I tell to Eclipse to generate methods (*Add unimplemented methods* popup) from inherited interface/abstract class, can I configure it to make these methods `final` by default ?

I'm aware of the *Save actions* hook in Eclipse but there's no preconfigured action to specify something like: "Add final modifier to method signature" or am I missing something ?

Also, when I create a class, is there a way to check the *checkbox final* by default ? I know it's not hard to do it by hand but it could be useful for me in case I forgot to check it. I'm aware of this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397400/make-classes-final-by-default-in-eclipse) but in 2011 there was no answer (maybe now there's one !).

PS: you can assume I'm using the latest version of Eclipse (Mars - 4.5.0).

Comment: No need to specify `final` on methods of a `final` class. They are implicitly final. --- If you forgot the one click to check the "final" box, it only takes 6 keystrokes to type the word.

Comment: @Andreas I need to specify `final` on (non-abstract) methods in abstract classes

Answer (score 0):

Since I assume you don't like the answer given in the link you specified, which is to [create your own custom 'new class wizard' for Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871295/how-to-create-a-custom-new-class-wizard-for-eclipse), the answer is: **No**

Comment: I'm not against creating my own wizard, but the answers in the link we made reference to are a bit vague...